# (Paul Irish's) Infinite scrolling plugin is simply not working

Tags: jquery, html, tumblr, infinite-scroll

According the chrome's console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

I mostly copied the code from the demo page so I am perplexed as to why this does not work

My HTML is formatted as follows:

```
<div id='posts'>
        <div class='infoPost'>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="nav">
         <a id="next" href="/page/2" class="icon" >0</a>
</div>
```

and the jquery (in a script tag at the bottom of the page):

```
$('#posts').infinitescroll({
navSelector     : "#next:last",
nextSelector    : "a#next:last",
itemSelector    : "#posts div.infoPost"
});
```

This is being implemented on tumblr, using jquery version 1.9.1

Comment: "(Paul Irish's) Infinite scrolling plugin is simply not working" - are you sure? :)

Comment: Please post the full HTML code. I think you've an error in your code by checking which browser the user is using.

Comment: A question is considered off-topic if it doesn't contain enough code required to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

[jquery.browser was removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) Use an older version of jQuery, use the [migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme), or modify the infinite scrolling plugin to do an alternative check.

Edit: What version of the plugin are you using? I see no browser checks or references to msie in https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js Are you sure you're not calling $.browser.msie in your own code?

Comment: I bet the latest version of the plugin is perfect and he is using a really hard to find outdated one.